# Computing mutual information

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, computational-statistics, mutual-information

I have a problem when computing the mutual information between two variables.
Let's consider the following table:

```
             k=1       k=2       k=3    
c = 1         10        20         5    
c = 2          5         3        20
```

I want to calculate the mutual information between the class ($c$) and the cluster ($k$).

E.g., for $\text{MI}(c=1, k=1)$, I will calculate the $P(c,k)$ as follows:

```
             k=1            k~=1    
c=1        10/63           25/63    
c~=1        5/63           23/63
```

and I can calculate the MI based on the following:

$\text{MI}(c,k) = \sum_{c\in\{0,1\}} \sum_{k\in\{0,1\}} p(c,k)log_2 \frac{p(c,k)}{p(c)p(k)}$

In this case: I am getting the same MI for $(c=1, k=1)$ and $(c=2, k=1)$. What is the reason for this? How can I calculate the MI for each $(c,k)$ based on the first table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MI is between two random variables. In this case, $c$ and $k$ are random variables.

If you take $c=1$, it isn't really random anymore, and MI should be zero. Likewise for $k=1$.

(Also, one more thing to keep in mind is that your 'plug-in' estimation of MI is biased.)

EDIT: MI between $I(c=1)$ vs $I(k=1)$ where $I$ is the indicator function, is a different matter. Your double usage of the same variable confused me.

Now your $c$ only take 2 values, therefore, $I(c=1) = 1 - I(c=2)$. MI is invariant invertible transformation of variables, that's why $MI(I(c=1),I(k=1)) = MI(I(c=2),I(k=1))$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But how can I find the dependency between (c=1, k=1) and (c=2, k=1) ?

Comment: what do you mean by (c=1,k=1)? is that a random quantity?

Comment: For example I want to find the dependency between the cluster 1 (k=1) and a class (c=1).

Comment: what is random in $k=1$? It's always $k=1$. You can't quantify a statistical dependence if there's no randomness.

Comment: K and c are random variables here. I want to calculate the dependecy between a particular k and particular c. how to do it with MI?

Comment: Once you fix k = 1, it's no longer random!!

Comment: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_labeling#Mutual_Information

Comment: @user570593 I see. In that wikipedia page, the random variables are indicator functions of k=1 and c=1. That's the confusion.

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answeres. Still I have some problems. I want to calculate the dependancy between a class and a cluster. How can I find it using MI?

Comment: @user570593 You want to know if "being in this cluster or not" tells you anything about "having this class label or not". That's why you use the indicator function. And that's all good. If you had more than 2 clusters, the answer would be different. I think your problem is conceptual.

Comment: If MI(I(c=1),I(k=1))=MI(I(c=2),I(k=1)) what I understood is the dependancy between c=1 and k=1, and the dependancy between c=2 and k=1 is same (if I calculate it). I expect to have different values for MI(c=1, k=1) and MI(c=2, k=1) so that I can select some clusters which determined a class c. for e.g. a weighting sceme based on MI is explained in  http://lastlaugh.inf.cs.cmu.edu/alex/BagOfVisWords.MIR07.pdf

Comment: @user570593 If you know it is not cluster 2, you know immediately it is cluster 1. That's why it doesn't matter. It sounds like you have more than 2 clusters in reality in which case MI would work fine. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Lets say I have 50 clusters. The problem I have is when I calculate the MI(c=1, k=1) and MI(c=2, k=1) I am getting the same value. (e.g. from the table I have 3 clusters when I calculate MI(c=1, k=1) and MI(c=2, k=1) getting same values). If i get different values for MI(c=1, k=1) and MI(c=2, k=2) s.t. MI(c=1,k=1)>MI(c=2,k=1) I can conclude that the cluster k=1  has high dependency with the class c=1. But for all k=1,...K I am getting MI(c=1, k) = MI(c=2, k)

Comment: Don't you mean MI(I(c=1), I(k=1)) vs MI(I(c=1), I(k=2))? Why are you changing c? There are only 2 values for c. Your notation of c and k are not consistent in the previous comment, I think.

Comment: No..  I need  MI(I(c=1), I(k=1)) vs MI(I(c=2), I(k=1))

Comment: @user570593 so you have only 2 clusters, if 'c' means clusters.

Comment: No C means class and K means clusters. I want to find out the dependancy of a particular cluster with a class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11033/discussion-between-memming-and-user570593)