# Mutual Information larger than smaller one of both entropies?

Tags: r, machine-learning, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

Lot's of questions and good answers on mutual information e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72617/computing-mutual-information) out there and I think I get the concept which is also nicely explained on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). But I'm nervous that R's infotheo package is outputting some funny results... or I'm not getting it after all ;-)

In all self contained examples with synthetic data sets I tried I could not provoke this behaviour so I will not be able to provide a fully self contained example but after running

```
MI.matrix <- mutinformation(df)
```

I am getting the following results:

```
> MI.matrix[1,1]
[1] 0.4276829
```

So the entropy of the 1st variable (lets call it X) is ~0.43

```
> MI.matrix[440,440]
[1] 0.24493
```

So the entropy of the 440th variable (lets call it Y) is ~0.24

```
> MI.matrix[1,440]
[1] 0.4276829
```

So I(X;Y)=H(X) with H(X)>H(Y)?! If you refer to the [image on the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Entropy-mutual-information-relative-entropy-relation-diagram.svg), how can the shared portion be larger than the smaller one of the entropies?

Note: I have also seen examples where H(X)=0, H(Y)=y and I(X;Y)=y where to my understanding I(X;Y) should be 0 as well.

***Edit: after some more debugging I found the following:***

1. variable pairs which behave funny are one with lots of NAs
2. While infotheo throws no errors with NAs and I could not find a hint in the documentation that NAs are not allowed I get a very different and correct result when removing NAs.

Below you can see a table with three variables, one version with all NAs included (`df.temp`) which has 1282 cases and one with complete cases only (`df.temp.completecases`) which is down to 15 cases.
[image: data tables screen shot]

Computing the MI matrix for both of them yields the following:
[image: MI matrix screen shots]

So now the I(X;Y) values seem to make more sense but the H(X) values along the diagonal obviously suffer from kicking out all X rows where Y is NA. I think I'll end up having to to compute the whole thing twice: once the entropies on individual columns and a 2nd run on pairwise complete columns to get the correct mutual information.

Guess my question has changed to: anyone's got an idea how to efficiently limit the pairwise MI computations to complete cases for a given pair only? Something similar to `use=pairwisecomplete.obs` in the [cor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete this topic I would like to share my final version which combines the idea provided by BioLiason with parallelized loops using `foreach`. On small data sets this is in fact slower but on large data sets this is significantly faster, especially when running on some proper H/W.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(infotheo)

n <- 250 #creates an nXn matrix, the larger the more compute time is required
df <- (discretize(matrix(rnorm(n*n,n,n/10),ncol=n)))

## pairwise complete mutual information via nested for loop ##
start_for <- Sys.time()
ColPairMap<-function(df){
t <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df)))
colnames(t) <- colnames(df)
rownames(t) <- colnames(df)
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
               for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
                                c(1:ncol(df))
                                if (nrow(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),])>0) {
                                    t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),j], df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),i]))
                                } else {
                                    t[j,i] <- 0
                                }
               }
}
return(t)
}
ColPairMap(df)
end_for <- Sys.time()
end_for-start_for


## pairwise complete mutual information via nested foreach loop ##
start_foreach <- Sys.time()
ncl <- max(2,floor(detectCores()*0.75)) #number of cores
clst <- makeCluster(n=ncl,type="TERR") #create cluster
e <- new.env() #new environment to export libraries to cores
e$libs <- .libPaths()
clusterExport(clst, "libs", envir=e) #export required packages to all cores
clusterEvalQ(clst, .libPaths(libs)) #export required packages to all cores
clusterEvalQ(clst, { #export required packages to all cores
    library(infotheo)
})
registerDoParallel(cl = clst) #register cluster

t <- foreach (j=1:ncol(df), .combine="c") %:% #parallellized nested loop for computing normalized pairwise complete MI between all columns
        foreach (i=j:ncol(df), .combine="c", .packages="infotheo") %dopar% {
            combine="c"
            compl_cases <- complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)])
            if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
                natstobits(mutinformation(df[compl_cases,][,j], df[compl_cases,][,i]))
            } else {
                0
            }
        }

RCA_MI_Matrix <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df), dimnames = list(colnames(df), colnames(df))) #set-up empty matrix for MI values
RCA_MI_Matrix[lower.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix, diag=TRUE)] <- t #fill lower triangle with MI values from nested loop
RCA_MI_Matrix[upper.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix)] <- t(RCA_MI_Matrix)[upper.tri(RCA_MI_Matrix)] #mirror lower triangle of matrix into upper one
end_foreach <- Sys.time()
end_foreach-start_foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, mutual information between X and Y cannot be larger than either the entropy of X or the entropy of Y. Ever. To debug where you've gone astray: instead of passing in a 2D matrix, try passing in pairs of vectors as separate X and Y arguments, and see if you can make sense of the results you get that way. Also pay attention to the method argument; empirical entropy estimates can be very biased unless you have a huge dataset; but it looks like corrections for this are supported.

Comment: Hi @BioLiason, thanks for your comments, it's really good to hear that this is not as it should be! :-)
Since I cannot leave images in a comment I will update my question with my findings. It comes down how to handle NAs... I thought that with `infotheo` I had finally found a package which can do something like pairwise complete obeservations only thus handling NAs but it turns out that this does not seem to be working...

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from a former colleague I think I have a solution incl. a self contained example:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
v2 <- c(1,NA,3,NA,5,NA,7,NA,9,NA)
v3 <- c(NA,2,3,NA,NA,6,7,NA,7,NA)
v4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8,9,10)
df <- cbind.data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)


ColPairMap<-function(df){
t <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df)))
colnames(t) <- colnames(df)
rownames(t) <- colnames(df)
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
               for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
                                c(1:ncol(df))
                                if (nrow(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),])>0) {
                                    t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),j], df[complete.cases(df[,c(i,j)]),i]))
                                } else {
                                    t[j,i] <- 0
                                }
               }
}
return(t)
}


ColPairMap(df)
```

However, performance is not exactly great with large data sets so if anyone's got an idea how to improve on that...

Answer (score 0):

I've playing a bit more with this and the solution described above can still produce I(x;y)>max(H(x),H(y)). The reason is:

- in that nested loop for `i!=j` we can get fewer `complete.cases` than for `i==j`
- as a result I(x;y) can sometimes be computed on fewer rows than H(x) or H(y) which can result in I(x;y)>max(H(x),H(y))

To illustrate a small example:

```
ColPairMap<-function(df){ #function for pairwise removal of incomplete cases and subsequent MI computation per pair of variables
    t <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = ncol(df), dimnames = list(colnames(df), colnames(df)))
    df <- as.matrix(df)
    for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
        for (i in j:ncol(df)) {
            compl_cases <- complete.cases(df[, c(i, j)])
            if (sum(compl_cases) > 0) {
                t[j,i] <- natstobits(mutinformation(df[compl_cases, j], df[compl_cases, i], method="emp")) #using method="mm" can cause >1 after normalization!
            }
        }
    }
    lt <- lower.tri(t)
    t[lt] <- t[lt] + t(t)[lt]
    return(t)
}

# Easy, no missing data
V1<-c(6,4,1,5,21,5,21,21,21,9)
V2<-c(1,10,6,9,21,9,21,21,21,20)
test1<-cbind.data.frame(V1,V2)
ColPairMap(test1)

# Missing data in both variables but the same rows!
# Consequently the entropy for a single variable is being computed on the exact same rows as the mutual information!
# As a result, mutual information can never be larger than any of the two individual entropies!
V1<-c(6,4,1,NA,21,5,21,21,NA,9)
V2<-c(1,10,6,NA,21,9,21,21,NA,20)
test3<-cbind.data.frame(V1,V2)
ColPairMap(test3)

# Missing data in both variables but in different rows!
# This leads to the entropy for a single variable being computed on a larger set of rows than the mutual information!
# As a result, mutual information can be larger than both individual entropies!
V1<-c(6,4,1,5,NA,5,21,21,21,9)
V2<-c(1,10,6,NA,21,9,21,21,NA,20)
test2<-cbind.data.frame(V1,V2)
ColPairMap(test2)
```

How would you go about this? Accept this typically small imperfection or compute individual H(x) for every different y and normalize directly inside the function or ...?